# Reference on Casselman-Shalika formula for GL(n) and PGL(n)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, geometric-langlands

I am looking for reference on Casselman-Shalika formula for GL(n) and PGL(n) at finite place p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-52/issue-4/On-an-explicit-formula-for-class-1-Whittaker-functions-on/10.3792/pja/1195518347.full), Shintani proves the Casselman-Shalika(-Shintani) formula for GL(n). This preceded Casselman-Shalika's [paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=CM_1980__41_2_207_0) by a few years. Several of [Cogdell's](https://people.math.osu.edu/cogdell.1/) expository articles on L-functions have easy-to-read descriptions of the formula.